# grails fails to build war

Tags: grails, dependencies, war

Anyone has seen this issue before? What's the cause here?

> Error executing script War: loader constraint violation in interface
>   itable initialization: when resolving method
>   "groovy.util.XmlParser.setDocumentLocator(Lorg/xml/sax/Locator;)V"
>   the class loader (instance of
>   org/codehaus/groovy/grails/cli/support/GrailsRootLoader) of the
>   current class, groovy/util/XmlParser, and the class loader (instance
>   of ) for interface org/xml/sax/ContentHandler have
>   different Class objects for the type org/xml/sax/Locator used in the
>   signature
>
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)  at
>   _GrailsWar_groovy$_run_closure4.class$(_GrailsWar_groovy)  at
>   _GrailsWar_groovy$_run_closure4.$get$$class$groovy$util$XmlParser(_GrailsWar_groovy)
>   at _GrailsWar_groovy$_run_closure4.doCall(_GrailsWar_groovy:186)  at
>   War$_run_closure1.doCall(War.groovy:38)  at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)  at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)  at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)  at
>   gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)  at
>   gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)   at 
>   gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)  at 
>   gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)  at
>   gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)  at
>   gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)  at
>   gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)  at
>   gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)

**EDIT**: As answered by Tim and Peter below this issue is a typical xml-api lib getting in the way of classloader. After removing it from the ivy cache dir i was able to run the dependency-report and clearly see it being pulled in by hibernate->dom4j->xml-api . I ran the same report on another machine with the same code base and did not see this dependency being pulled in. So I am still trying to figure out what caused this issue in the first place. The quick fix for me was to add the following in the BuildConfig

```
inherits("global") {
       excludes ( "xml-apis", "commons-digester")
    }
```

Comment: I guess that you should declare GRAIL_HOME variable as system variable

Comment: What plugins do you have installed?

Comment: u mean GRAILS_HOME and yes it is set, otherwise u can't even run grails. As far as plugins I have a bunch: app-info, spring-security, jms, mail, clover, audit-logging, hibernate, tomcat

Comment: Can you run grails dependency-report? If that doesn't work, I suggest including plugins and JARs via the dependency DSL and excluding "xml-apis" from everything. Note that we automatically exclude these troublesome JARs in Grails 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sounds like something](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/dependencies-and-build-scripts-td2311594.html) has pulled the `xml-apis` module into your classpath.

GroovyWS is sometimes the culprit.  Have you added anything to the dependencies recently?

I assume the project used to work...so it must be something someone has added recently

Looking back through your source control might help you see what it is...

Or it could be something someone stuck in JAVA_HOME/lib/ext?

Comment: I went to my C:\Users\<user>\.ivy2\cache dir and opened up org.grails.internal-<MyProject>-runtime.xml file and sure enough there was xml-api dependency from dom4j from hibernate core. I deleted it from ivy cache and temporarily things work again.

Comment: Did you try Grails 1.4 or 2.0 and then switch back to Grails 1.3? If so, that was probably the cause of the problem. In this case, a reliable solution is to add an `excludes "xml-apis", "commons-digester"` to the `inherits "global"` block.

Comment: Peter, thank you very much for your comment and suggestion. Adding 
       excludes ( "xml-apis", "commons-digester")
to the BuildConfig has indeed fixed the problem. I am still puzzled at how this dependency crept in there as other machines with the same code base do not have this issue. I did not (to my knowledge) upgrade the grails version, we are at 1.3.7